# Select box with the months of the year default value being the current month in Angular

Tags: angular, select

I have a select box in Angular and I want to have the months of the year as options and the default value to be the current month. Is there a way to do this dynamically? Maybe with moment.
So far this is what I have:

```
    <select class="input">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>JUNE</option>
        <option>JANUARY</option>
        <option>FEBRUARY</option>
        <option>MARCH</option>
        <option>APRIL</option>
        .....
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set value Dynamically we can use `ngModal` .
first change your html code like this

```
 <select class="input" [(ngModel)]="month">
    <option *ngFor="let x in allmonths" [value]="x.id">{{x.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

next declare a variable in your component like this

```
allmonths = [
    {name:'JANUARY',key:0},
    {name:'FEBRUARY',key:1},
    {name:'APRIL',key:2},
    {name:'MARCH',key:3},
    {name:'APRIL',key:4},
    {name:'JUNE',key:5},
    {name:'JULAY',key:6},
    {name:'AUGUST',key:7},
    {name:'SEPTEMBER',key:8},
    {name:'OCTOBER',key:9},
    {name:'NOVEMBER',key:10},
    {name:'DECEMBER',key:10}]
```

this will list out all the months in view

to select current  month default please add this to your `ngOnInit` method

```
this.month = new Date().getMonth()
```